# index.html being loaded as one of my data models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using Ember-CLI with Ember 2.2.0 and Ember Data 2.0. This problem was happening before I upgraded my ember-cli to the latest ember.

I have a fairly simple Ember app. There is a 'users' file on my server hard coded for testing with some json of some sample user accounts. https://example.com/users

```
{"users": [{"id":1,"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"blah","email":"blah@example.com","password":"blah","phone":"212-555-1212","isActive":"true"},{"id":2,"firstName":"George","lastName":"blah","email":"blah2@example.com","password":"blah","phone":"310-555-1212","isActive":"true"}]}
```

On my development machine I have a generated Ember-cli app with the following modifications:

```
router.js
...
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users', function() {});
});
```

...

```
users.hbs
<h1>Users Route</h1>

<h1>Users Index</h1>
<Table>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Phone</th>
</tr>

{{#each users as |user|}}
<tr>
<td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
<td>{{user.email}}</td>
<td>{{user.phone}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}

</table>
{{outlet}}
```

in my routes folder:

```
user.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    }
});
```

Ember throws the following parsing error when it tries to access the users model:

Error while processing route: users.index Unexpected token < SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I can clearly see in the ember inspector that it is trying to parse my index.html page!! WTH??

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>UserMan</title>
....
```

Even if I go to the ember inspector, and go to the users route, then try and access the model using the store:

```
$E.store.findAll('user')
```

The parsing error happens and its clearly trying to parse the index.html page again.

Any ideas where ember is going wrong? Or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see an ajax request being made to `users` ? Do you have an adapter (JSONAPIAdapter, ou RESTAdapter?)

Comment: @PedroRio I'm using a RESTAdapter.  My bad for not mentioning that in my original post.

Comment: And do you see an ajax request being made to the `users`endpoint? what does the request look like, what does the response look like?

Also, you mention that your route is `users` but your route file (in your code says `user.js` (singular) while the other files are `users.*`

Comment: Sorry for the late response due to the holidays. I started a new project but getting same error. Yes an Ajax call is being made. Here are the headers: (Request URL:http://localhost:4200/users
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:[::1]:4200) and (cf-ray:2607e5c1249239ca-PHX
connection:close
date:Wed, 06 Jan 2016 13:51:24 GMT
etag:"126-527627451f578"
server:cloudflare-nginx
set-cookie:__cfduid=dc615eecd5c2528619c200693563db7b41452088284; expires=Thu, 05-Jan-17 13:51:24 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By:Express
Request Headers
view source
)

Comment: Here is a portion of my response: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>UserMan2</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Lastly, here is the way i am calling Ember Server: ember server --proxy https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working. Here are the steps that I had to take:
1) turn off the proxy setting in Ember Server (this just doesn't appear to work)
2) Change the users file in Apache2 configuration file to ForceType application/json
3) Enable CORS by Header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
4) use the host: http://example.com in the RESTAdapter